# Should I deploy my backend in a different VM from my frontend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up a staging environment for my web application using GCP. I deployed my frontend, a react app, in a VM instance and set up a load balancer to serve https traffic. I set up a Dockerfile for my frontend that builds the frontend and serves the app using Nginx. The VM is running a container from my Dockerfile. Locally in my dev environment, my frontend communicates with my Java backend on localhost:8080, which is running by deploying a jar file.

My frontend communicates to my Java backend through http calls. Should I deploy the backend in a separate VM instance using a different Dockerfile, or should I deploy it to the same VM that's hosting my frontend? What are the pros and cons of each option?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `frontend`. Typically, you can run many services on the same virtual machine. Edit your post and clearly define what you have deployed and where each section of code (service) executes. If your frontend code is running in the user's browser, then why would you need to add another VM in addition to the one running Java?

Comment: Less servers means lower cost. However it depends of your website. Why are you using VM with a container instead of serverless solution like Cloud Run where you pay when your container serve a request and 0 the rest of the time? Anyway, no problem to run all the processes on the same instance, it will reduce the server cost and the maintenance overhead. However, if you think about scalability, you can't scale independently the front and the back. That's why separate layer/server are better for that.

Comment: edited my post. @JohnHanley it's true that multiple services can be run on the same VM, but I'm thinking about deploying my backend (and maybe even my postgres db) on separate VMs so I can scale them independently. I know I'm definitely going to do this in my production environment and I figure my staging environment can mimic my prod environment.

Comment: well, hopefully my application will be in high demand and require high availability in the future. I never claimed that separation is the same as scaling - I simply mean that the backend and frontend can be scaled independently if they're running on different VMs

Comment: To circle back to what @guillaumeblaquiere said, you might be better off with scaling your app when you go for serverless solutions like Cloud Run instead of hosting it on your own VM. The same might be true for the DB...